# Do the Elf creatures put into the battlefield by Planeswalker Nissa Revane suffer from summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The 3rd ability of [Nissa Revane Planeswalker](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Nissa%20Revane) is

- -7: Search your library for any number of Elf creature cards and put them onto the battlefield. Then shuffle your library.

So the question is do the Elf creature cards put into the battlefield as a result of this ability suffer from summoning sickness?

Comment: Summoning sickness is a pretty all-encompassing rule of Magic, that overrides almost any other consideration in the game.  Unless a creature has Haste: if it didn't start the turn on the battlefield and under your control, it has summoning sickness.  A card has to be pretty explicit about the creature not having summoning sickness if it wants to get around this rule: e.g. all the red cards that all you to untap a creature and gain control of it till end of turn.  Such cards always have a clause reading something like "That creature gains haste till end of turn".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**,

From the [Comprehensive](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20110204.txt) rules:

> 302.6. A creature's activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can't be activated unless the creature has been under its controller's control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can't attack unless it has been under its controller's control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the "summoning sickness" rule.

Any elf with Haste ignores that restriction as usual of course.

Answer (score 8):

Any creature in play that wasn't in play at the start of the turn suffers summoning sickness. So yes, the Elves will have summoning sickness. Here's the [official rule](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules):

> 302.6. A creature's activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap
>   symbol in its activation cost can't be
>   activated unless the creature has been
>   under its controller's control
>   continuously since his or her most
>   recent turn began. A creature can't
>   attack unless it has been under its
>   controller's control continuously
>   since his or her most recent turn
>   began. This rule is informally called
>   the "summoning sickness" rule.

Comment: Unless, of course, there is an effect on the board (like an enchantment) that gives haste to creatures, or at least to creatures with a property that the elf has.