# What state and trigger events apply when you "put creatures onto the battlefield?"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For instance, the *-8 ability* for [Liliana Vess](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383300) says,

> Put all creature cards from all graveyards onto the battlefield under
>   your control.

This *sounds* distinct from casting/summoning, and there's no casting cost paid, which might imply (to me) that there's no summoning sickness. But, these creatures are also technically *entering* the battlefield, which implies that those abilities would trigger. Is that correct?

- Do the creatures enter without summoning sickness?
- Do "when this card enters the battlefield" abilities activate?
- Are there other potential "casting" or "playing" abilities that could trigger?

Comment: The question about summoning sickness is a duplicate of [Do the Elf creatures put into the battlefield by Planeswalker Nissa Revane suffer from summoning sickness?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/2992/6692)

Comment: @Rainbolt Since the other two bullets aren't answered there, do you think this question needs to just be edited?

Comment: I would just leave it alone for now, and in the future strive to ask one question per post. It's not a big deal unless *all* of the questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When/whenever this/a creature enters the battlefield [...]

... triggers when it enters the battlefield. It wasn't on the battlefield, and then it was. Moving things from the graveyard to the battlefield with Liliana counts.

> When/whenever you cast [...]

... triggers when you cast a spell. Moving things around with Liliana doesn't count as casting a spell.

> When/whenever you play [...]

... triggers when you play. Playing means casting a spell or playing a land. Moving things around with Liliana doesn't count as playing.

If you haven't controlled a creature since the beginning of your turn, then it has summoning sickness. If Liliana moves a creature from your graveyard to the battlefield, then it hasn't been under your control since the beginning of the turn, and so it has summoning sickness.

Answer (score 2):

It is distinct from casting or summoning. It is placing the creature onto the battlefield without casting. Normally creatures enter the battlefield by casting, but it's not the only way.

So:

- It doesn't trigger any "when you cast" abilities
- The creatures enter the battlefield, so they trigger "When this creature enters the battlefield" abilities
- The creature wasn't under your control since the beginning of the turn, so they have summoning sickness.