# How to grant haste en masse in a mono-green Commander deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In my Elf Commander Deck (edited version of the [Guided by Nature 2014 Commander Deck](http://magic.wizards.com/en/products/card-set-archive/commander-2014/guided-by-nature)), I have [Nissa Revane](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190411) and as I was looking through the MTG tag of BCGSE I saw [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/do-the-elf-creatures-put-into-the-battlefield-by-planeswalker-nissa-revane-suffe) asking about if elves summoned with Nissa's -7 ability have summoning sickness. Since the answer is yes, I was wondering if there is a green or colorless card that I would be able to use to counter their summoning sickness (preferably an elf that grants other elves haste). Is there a card that would be able to fit into the restrictions of my deck?

Comment: One thing to consider, do you need to give the creatures haste en-masse? A [Heedless One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393967) with [Swiftfoot Boots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405406) or a similar artifact would do the trick. Combine with [Wirewood Hivemaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=43794) and she should get big enough.

Comment: In addition to @ghoppe, you can use [mtg:Ivy Lane Denizen]. He sees each elf entering with him, so you can order the effects.

Comment: Could this question not have been answered trough the use of a simple gatherer search?

Comment: @NeilMeyer The reason why I was asking it on here is because I was hoping for an Elf that would have granted haste (which I did try searching for).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple search for cards with the words "creatures" and "haste" in their text boxes reveals a couple cards with Green color identity that grant mass haste:

- [Akroma's Memorial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136150) is an artifact that grants your creatures Haste, along with a few other abilities.
- [Concordant Crossroads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Concordant%20Crossroads) grants **all** creatures Haste, not just yours.
- [Reflex Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reflex%20Sliver) gives all your Slivers Haste and [Hivestone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hivestone) makes all your creatures Slivers, so together they give all your creatures Haste.

Answer (score 2):

[Crashing Drawbridge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrashing%20Drawbridge%5d) from Eldraine taps to give all of your creatures haste for the turn.